# Newer apt repositories on older Ubuntu releases

Tags: apt

If I have an older Ubuntu release, lets say it is Ubuntu 10.04, and I have to install a package from a newer Ubuntu apt repositories (e.g. from Ubuntu 11.10 repo's) because the newer versions of that package have a feature which I require most. What is the best way of installing the package without affecting or upgrading other packages. [Here is](http://www.rrfx.net/2011/02/wpa2-enterprise-on-ubuntu-configuring.html) what I want to do. But the solution explained there Updates other packages which I don't require.

Comment: The article you linked is too long. Can you summarize the relevant bits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't mention the specific package, so I can only give generalities.

If possible, the easiest thing would be to find the appropriate `.deb` on [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) and install it. As long as the requisite dependencies are available in your version of Ubuntu, it'll work great.

A second, more involved option would be to rebuild the source package using your version of Ubuntu. This would resolve certain classes of dependency problems. Look into `pbuilder` for this.

Finally, you could try compiling the upstream version yourself, using `checkinstall`. This should only be a last resort, however.

One of these options will likely work for you. If they don't, then you might not have too many options, as it would mean that there are some critical dependencies that can't really be resolved without a system upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Well you are sort of stuck in that is what is meant by dependencies.

Say you have a package, foo-1.0 , and it depends on bar-1.0

And you want to upgrade to foo-2.0 , and it depends on bar-2.0

so you can not upgrade foo (reliably) without upgrading bar

If you want to install the newer package, either accept the dependencies (probably easiest) or upgrade Ubuntu.

If you think the dependencies are not accurate, best contact the maintainer of the ppa or file a bug report.